# Problem running a powershell command containing path with spaces inside multiple nested quotes using node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell

### Explanation

I'm trying to run the command bellow from within Node js:

```
child_process.exec(`powershell -command "Start-Process cmd '/k cd /d \"${path}\"' -Verb RunAs"`)
```

Which powershell receives in the formatted form:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process cmd '/k cd /d "E:\test"' -Verb RunAs"
```

### Goal

The goal is to open specified directory in a new `cmd` window from node.js:

- Open `cmd` as administrator by using powershell (if there's a better way, please let me know)
- Run specified command in `cmd` which opens a new `cmd` window and changes the directory

### Problem

It does work for paths without spaces, like `E:\test`, but doesn't work for paths like `E:\test name` (contains space).
I get the following error:

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
```

I tried using back ticks to escape some nested quotes but it didn't help:

```
"Start-Process cmd '/k cd /d `"E:\test name`"' -Verb RunAs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes, because `\"` becomes `"` in your string but it should stay as `\"` in the final string, so replace `\"` with `\\"`.

```
child_process.exec(`powershell -command "Start-Process cmd '/k cd /d \\"${path}\\"' -Verb RunAs"`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the it still doesn't work for paths that contain spaces e.g. `E:\test name` for some reason those quotes around the path are ignored

Comment: I just tested it with `child_process.exec(\`powershell -command "Start-Process cmd '/k cd /d \\"P:\\tes t\\"' -Verb RunAs"\`);` and it works fine. I even made it works with your first command. You might also make sure that \ are escaped in your path with something like `${path.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')}`

Comment: Thank you, yeah, you're right, it works! Turns out that it doesn't work only if there's special characters in the path, e.g. `E:\test & name`. That't why it didn't work for me, I was testing it on a path with not just spaces but also a special character `&`

Comment: I made it work with the special characters. All you need to do is to add double quotes around it e.g. replace `&` with `"&"`. Something like this: `path.replace(/([!@#$%^&*()_+])/g, '\"$1\"')`